# Order of adverb "immediately" in a phrase

Tags: adverbs

I've been struggling with this aspect of the English language and I don't know if there are some rules to it that can help me. I've looked for answers on the internet but so far I haven't found anything that can help me clear my mind on this issue.

I was writing this phrase:

> "I called at your offices immediately to report the situation and I was assured that it would be repaired soon"

Is there a rule of when the "immediately goes"?

I could rephrase it into this:

> "I immediately called at your offices to report the situation and I was assured that it would be repaired soon"

Or even:

> "I called immediately at your offices to report the situation and I was assured that it would be repaired soon" (a grammar tool I have on my computer suggests in this particular phrase to change the at to a "to")

Are any of those interchangeable?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They're all fine. Don't change *at* to *to*. To *call at* means that you went there yourself. *To call* implies that you phoned. *To call to* is not correct. You can *call to* people (meaning to shout out to) but not to offices.

Answer (score 1):

To "call at" is either nautical, regarding ships, or else perhaps a britishism?
Usually we just say call. "Call their office."

> I called your offices immediately to report the situation

Ok

> I immediately called your offices to report the situation

Ok

> I called immediately your offices to report the situation

No

Comment: "I called your office" normally means "I telephoned" while "I called **at** your office" means "I went there". I think this sense of "called at" is more common in the UK, in the US "I visited" or "I went to" would be much more common.

Comment: @DavidSiegel, yes.  "I visited" or "went to" or "stopped by", rather than "called at"

Comment: there is nothing wrong with "called at". I have used it occasionally. It just not as common in US English.